# Delaying Application to Previous Company

Tags: interviewing, applications

Some days ago I met the owner of my previous company (it's not a really big company), let's call it company A.

He asked if I still have his contact and my personal name card (which I don't have). He then said they need some people.

Some days after I met him, I sent him an email to keep in touch with him along with my personal contact. He replied me that they are looking for a person for specific vacancy and asks me if I am keen to apply.

However, currently I am in midst of applying other company (company B) and just got reply from them that I am invited for interview.

I am now in my birth country and those companies are abroad. The country those company reside in, is strictly process 1 application only to get the working visa.

How can I delay my application to my previous company, company A without making them negative thinking, because I don't want to break our relationship?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/260382) since I would guess that a company won't actually apply for a visa for you until you've accepted their offer so you wouldn't ever have  companies applying for a visa for you at the same time. However, the real question, "Does applying to multiple companies in [Country] complicate the working visa request?" is off-topic here.

Comment: Hmm my real question is still to how to delay my application to company A since it may affect the working visa process if both companies accept me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why would you delay applying with company A? You have only been invited to an interview with company B.

That interview could be delayed, or cancelled; or you could mess it up; or they could have better candidates; or the job might not be as good as described.

Always keep putting applications in until you get to the point where you have found a job. And by found a job I mean they have given you a written offer, and you have accepted it.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct. However, optimistically, if I am accepted by both companies, it may bring bad things if both know that I am applying to both companies when they try to apply my working visa to their country ministry (I am more concerned to relationship between me and company A, which may have higher rate to get job there again). I do not intend to act arrogant, just thinking further possibilities or maybe too far lol..

Comment: Applying for jobs is not marriage, you don't have to only do it one at a time. I assume it is not a secret that you seeking employment? You are free to tell all your applications that you are currently applying for work. It's up to the companies that are interested in you to make you an offer, and then it is up to you to choose which one of your offers you would like to accept. @JonW

Comment: @JonW "if I am accepted by both companies" Note that that won't ever happen though: both may **offer** you the job but you'd only accept one of them.

Comment: Agreed! Thanks! Missed the process of offer decision!